# Why i get ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS on that code

Tags: php, redirect, submit, token, form-submit

Not everytime, browsers chrome, firefox, iexplorer returns to me error with redirects and they go in stuck (i need to delete cookies)
In that code:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $_SESSION['submit']=true;
}

if (isset($_POST['submit']) || ( isset($_SESSION['submit']) && $_SESSION['submit'])) {
   if($_SESSION['user_token'] == $_POST['user_token']) {
       if (isset($_POST['submit1'])) {
            unset($_SESSION['user_token']);
                $_SESSION['submit']=false;
                include_once('./token.php');
                include_once('./my3page.php');
       }
       include_once('./my2page.php'); //**PAGE WITH BUTTON NAMED SUBMIT1**
   } else {
      header("location: ./index.php");
   }
} else {
    include_once('./token.php');
    include_once('./my1page.php'); //**PAGE WITH BUTTON NAMED SUBMIT**
}
```

For reproduce the error one of the methods is only press SUBMIT button without type anything (my1page contains a search form)

Comment: because when your page loads the `header("location: ./index.php");` is immediately getting executed. So, when this happens repeatedly you'll get that error. Make sure to have some logic to prevent automatic and repeated redirection

Comment: How i can correct this? I would like to redirect to index.php only if token is expired! my1page is a search form with submit1, my2page is a table populated from mysql db with submit2, my3page are 2 query (UPDATE) with results. I would like to avoid double insertions and so i'm using a token

Comment: Try this on the `6` line: `if(@$_POST['user_token'] && @$_SESSION['submit'])`

Comment: Once that works try to build a better if() logic without using `@`

Comment: @samayo sorry it work! before i wrong (i replace `if($_SESSION['user_token'] == $_POST['user_token'])` instead `if (isset($_POST['submit']) || ( isset($_SESSION['submit']) && $_SESSION['submit']))`

Comment: greate... and try to clean up your code. The whole code can be minimized to just 4 lines

Comment: how? I don't know how! Thanks a lot